# PlaceHolder Javascript files

Tags: javascript, validation

I am developing a web application for a company, I use Javascript files to validate client side form fields.
In those JavaScript files I show error messages if the user entered wrong data in the form fields.

For example I have this code in my JavaScript files:

```
if(bad_validation)
alert("Error message")
```

My question is, how can I replace the message inside the `alert` function by a "placeholder" and in compilation time, the compiler switch the placeholder by the correct message.
I want to centralize all the Javascript messages in one kind of error file, something like this:

```
error.message.wrong_data = "wrong data"
error.message.wrong_age = "wrong age"
```

And in my JavaScript code I will put something like

```
alert('error.message.wrong_data')
```

If the answer is too large can you give some clues in how can I search on the web by this subject, or point me some tutorials about this.
I am using Eclipse and tomcat to run the web application.

Comment: umm, javascript does not do any compiling...

Comment: What "compilation time" are you referring to here?

Comment: I am referring the Java compilation, in this specific case it is the eclipse that do it under the hood , i am not using ant for example to compile the project and deploy it in Tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

I would put your messages in one file, say `errMsgs.js` and then this file would contain something like:

```
var ErrMsg = {
    wrong_data: "You've put in some invalid data",
    wrong_age: "Invalid age entered"
};
```

And then use it in your pages like:

```
alert(ErrMsg.wrong_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I follow correctly you would like to be able to define the error message?

Do the following:

```
var error_message = 'Error message'; 

if(bad_validation_flag){
   alert(error_message);
}
```

You would define your `error_message` while doing your validation, and make sure your `bad_message_flag` just kicks up the alert.  You can also append more errors to the `error_message` var as needed.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be using a server-side technology that you do not mention in your post (compile time?) and be looking for a way to do string replacement with that. If that is not the case and you really intend to do this with Javascript my guess is that you are trying to do localization. Here is a localization library that does what you want: http://eligrey.com/blog/post/passive-localization-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can create a resource bundle (check ExtJS and GWT implementation) and replace messages in runtime. Alternatively, you can add to your compilation routine procedure that will replace certain variables by specific values taken from .properties file (like in L10N)

Comment: can you give some example related to alternative that you refer in the above post ? Thanks

Comment: @tt0686, do you use a cruncher in your build process?